# Throws in method signature of constructor

Tags: java, constructor, throws

I have two constructors below and both executed just fine.  Normally, Intellij will fuss at me if I didn't include throws in the method signature of the constructor, but in this particular instance, Intellij didn't bring up any errors.  What would be the cause of this?  I was taught to always put throws in the method signature if that method were to throw an exception.  Is this a bug with Intellij?

```
protected PayCalculator(double payRate) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (payRate >= 0)
            this.payRate = payRate;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pay rate cannot be less than zero");
    }

// versus

protected PayCalculator(double payRate) {
        if (payRate >= 0)
            this.payRate = payRate;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pay rate cannot be less than zero");
    }
```

Comment: It's a `RuntimeException`, so it's unchecked. You don't need to declare unchecked exceptions in the throws clause (but you should document them)

Comment: IntelliJ  tells you to throw error if it is a checked exception. Here IllegalArgumentException is a Runtime Exception, which is unchecked, So no need to define in the method signature

Comment: Oh yeah that’s right, that makes sense!  Thanks @user.

Comment: Thanks @Abhinaba Chakraborty

Answer (score 1):

An `IllegalArgumentException` is a subtype of a `RuntimeException`. So just like an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it doesn't need to be caught or thrown. Think of it like this snippet of Code

```
int foo() {
  int[] bar = new int[2];
  return bar[10];
}
```

This inevitably will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but it'll compile just fine.